# Using Clojurescript with Light Table

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lighttable

I have been trying to use Clojure Script with Light Table and lein-cljs without much success.

The main problem seems to be with dependencies.  It seems like evaluating a cljs `(ctrl-shift-enter)` page does not recursively evaluate the dependencies.  The result of this is that I have to manually evaluate each dependent file.  If I refresh the HTML page, or make a change I have to do this all over again.  Other times evaluating a page doesn't work, and just gives me good not found error.

Clearly this is not usable.  Am I doing something wrong? For Clojure it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is probably a bad place to learn more about Light Table.  I'd drop into the Light Table channel at #lighttable on irc.freenode.net.  Somebody can help you there!